# Is there a way to receive Twitter group notices in identi.ca?

Tags: twitter, identi.ca

I'm evaluating [identi.ca](http://identi.ca/), and [it looks very attractive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/10298). One extra nice feature would be the ability to subscribe to a Twitter feed (what's the correct terminology), especially because Twitter is practically the only player in the industry.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the StatusNet software that Identi.ca is based on should support subscribing to Twitter but, last time I checked (maybe a year ago), they were still be working on making it performant enough to be enabled for installations as big as Identi.ca.

Comment: Identi.ca works with http://pump.io/ now, not StatusNet.